# Restrict area/rectangle selection to a limited area in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, margin

I need to select a region inside another region using the mouse, but I get offset problems when I set a margin for the region containing the selection.

I'm not really sure why this is happening, how do I fix this behavior?

```js
var div = document.getElementById('selection'),
  x1 = 0,
  y1 = 0,
  x2 = 0,
  y2 = 0;

function reCalc() {
  var x3 = Math.min(x1, x2);
  var x4 = Math.max(x1, x2);
  var y3 = Math.min(y1, y2);
  var y4 = Math.max(y1, y2);
  div.style.left = x3 + 'px';
  div.style.top = y3 + 'px';
  div.style.width = x4 - x3 + 'px';
  div.style.height = y4 - y3 + 'px';
}
onmousedown = function(e) {
  div.hidden = 0;
  x1 = e.clientX;
  y1 = e.clientY;
  reCalc();
};
onmousemove = function(e) {
  x2 = e.clientX;
  y2 = e.clientY;
  reCalc();
};
onmouseup = function(e) {
  div.hidden = 1;
};
```

```css
#selection {
  border: 1px dotted #000;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: teal;
  opacity: 0.5;
  margin: 0px 0px;
}

#div {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div">

  <div id="selection" hidden></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just remove `margin: 50px;` from `#div`'s css or is it really needed there? If so add a `margin: -50px;` on `#selection`

Comment: Okay, adding the margin worked.